# Limiting the number of characters per line in css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

How can I make sure that 50 characters are shown in block (`width:100px;`) with CSS if User posts 50 characters on one line.
 Now, my view is below.

```
<div class='example-wrapper'>
  <%= simple_format(@user.content , class:'example')  %>
</div>
```

If User posts 50 characters on one line(without making a line break) in @user.content, it is sticking out from browser.I don't mean that I use `overflow:hidden;`. Although I use `white-space:normal;`, nothing changes. 
The error is shown the following picture. I want to show all characters.

[image]

Please tell me how to do it.

Now, scss is below.

```
.example-wrapper{
  background-color:red;
  max-width:100px;
}
.example{
  max-width:100px;
  white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS solution or a Ruby one? The title and text don't seem to match?

Comment: Sorry, I am looking for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you properly, you can use word-wrap property like this:

```
.example-wrapper {
  background-color: red;
  max-width: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.example {
  max-width: 100px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

The word-wrap property allows long words to be able to be broken and wrap onto the next line.

Comment: Oh!!!This is great!! I don't know word-wrap. Thank you for your helping!

Comment: You're welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. Please check this link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: I don't know it... Thank you!

Comment: Oh..Sorry for that.